# How to not load the children of a ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter, dart, expandablelistview

I have the follow structure: A list of Expansion tiles > clicking on it, opens another list of ExpansionTiles > Clicking in one of them, it should open some widgets according to a SQL query.

The problem is, when I tap in the first Expansion Tile it loads all the widgets from all the Expansion Tiles inside the first option making the query very slow. I want to only load the widgets when I tap in the second one (loading only the necessary ones)

Here is the code:

- 1st list:

```dart
class ListItemsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListItemsScreenState createState() => _ListItemsScreenState();
}
class _ListItemsScreenState extends State<ListItemsScreen> {

final Widget appBar = AppBar(
    title: Text('ITEMS'),
    actions: [
      Builder(
        builder: (context) => IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .pushNamed(ROUTE_CHART);
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final List items = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

return Scaffold(
        appBar: appBar,
        body: items == null || items.isEmpty ?
        Center(child: Text("0 items here"),)
            :
        ListView(
          children: [
            ...items.map<Widget>(
                  (item) {
                return ExpansionTile(
                    leading: Image.asset(ASSET_IMAGE,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover
                    ),
                    title: Text('${item.code}  |  ${item.description}'),
                    subtitle:
                    Text('${item.color}'),
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: ProductWidget(item),
                      ),
                    ],
                    ),

                );
              },
            )
          ],
        )
    );
```

- 2nd list (ProductWidget):

```dart
class ProductWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Product product;

  ProductWidget(this.produto);

  @override
  _ProductWidgetState createState() => _ProductWidgetState();
}

class _ProdutoGradeWidgetState extends State<ProdutoGradeWidget> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: product.stream,
          builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
              return SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((ctx, i) {
                  if (i == 0) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                              child: Text(
                                'I HAVE THIS PRODUCT IN THESE COLORS',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color:
                                  Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color,
                                ),
                              )
                            ),
                          ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        ProductColorsWidget(color: snapshot.data[i]),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else if (i == snapshot.data.length - 1) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        ProductColorsWidget(color: snapshot.data[i]),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              'Qtd',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color:
                                Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                  return ProductColorsWidget(color: snapshot.data[i]);
                }, childCount: snapshot.data.length),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
}
}
```

- 3rd part (Product Colors Widget where I list the second Expansion Tiles):

```dart
class ProductColorsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ColorProduct color;

  ProdutoCorGradeWidget({this.color});


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ExpansionTile(
        maintainState: true,
        tilePadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        title: Text(
          '${color.id} - ${color.description}',
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .subtitle1
              .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
        childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        children: [
          Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  ...color.sizes.map<Widget>(
                          (item) {
                        return Column(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                  child: Text(
                                    item.description, textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  )
                              ),
                              ...item.prices.map<Widget>((size) {
                                return PricesWidget( //here it should show the widgets according to the second ExpansionTiles
                                    color: color,
                                    size: size
                                );
                              })
                            ]
                        );
                      }
                  )
                ],
              )
          )
        ],

      );
  }
}
```

So, to be clear, what I want is: First It lists the products (with expansionTiles), expanding one it should show the second Tiles (with sizes) and after selecting one it should show the widgets.

..But what is happening now is: List the products and when I select one the app loads all the widget from all the second 'expansionTiles' making it slow to show the second list.  What should I do?

Comment: Could you post whole classes instead of just build methods?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with

```
ExpansionTile(
    maintainState: true,
    .....
)
```

I had a similar issue in which I had an ExpansionTile that was its own child and it caused a stack overflow because it was building them all. After setting maintainState to false the problem was solved.

You might have to adapt your state management according to that the children state may not be saved